# Asp.net v2.0 vs asp.net v3.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have my gui which has this in its webconfig:

```
<compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            **<providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>**
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
```

Now when i go in the IIS and within the website properties select the asp.net version of v2.0.50727 (as i can see no higher version).. everything works fine

but now when i use another server of win 2003 i get an error

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Child nodes not allowed.

at this line:

i saw some answers which said that the server must not have v3.5... but i have selected v2.0.50727 so why do i need v3.5, also then how did it work in the previous server..

Please help..
thanks

Comment: Asp.Net v3.5 uses the same compiler as in v2.0.50727. You don't need to mention it. This is why you don't see anything higher in IIS also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as ASP.Net is concerned, 3.5 is mostly just a set of extensions for the 2.0 runtime.  You still use a .Net 2.0 App Pool to run web apps built with .Net 3.5.  However, you do need to make sure that .Net 3.5 is installed on the server, or the extensions won't be available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. so why is it showing me the error in my webconfig.?

Comment: i mean where can i check if .net 3.5 is installed.. i have to do this on a client machine... or else i would have just downloaded again

Comment: You can check your .Net versions by going to: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework

Comment: thanks i will mark this answer once i solve the clients problem.. or ill come back with another question.. but i feel this is right